# Easy HTML/CSS Help. Can't seem to figure this out!

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up some text between two images on its left and right. Why isn't it moving up?

```
<img src="srchere" /><span style="padding-bottom:10px;">Some text right here!</span><img src="srchere" />
```

The two images are larger than the text, so it looks like the text isn't aligned and is positioned lower than the images. How do I raise the text up? The code I have above doesn't seem to move the text up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want images to vertically align with text, you need to use:

```
vertical-align: middle
```

Note that your `padding-bottom` might throw this off a little.

Also, if you are not already doing it, you should use an external stylesheet instead of inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust manually, this can do

```
<span style="vertical-align:100%">
```

increase/decrease the percentage until u satisfy

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="srchere" />
<span>Some text right here!</span>
<img src="srchere" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display:block;
}
img {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
}
img, span {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `align="absmiddle"` attribute to the images.

Answer (score 0):

By "up" I assume you mean aligned to the top of the container box. This should do what you want:

```
<img style="float: left;" src="...">
<p style="float: left;">Filler text. Filler text. Filler text.</p>
<img style="float: right;" src="...">
```